# Invoking Bootstrap Datetimepicker through class rather than id

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, datetimepicker

I am curious to know how I can invoke the bootstrap datetimepicker ([More info](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)) through class attribute rather than the id.

Here is my HTML

```
<input class="form-control dateclass" placeholder="Date of visit 1" />
<input class="form-control dateclass" placeholder="Date of visit 2" />
<input class="form-control dateclass" placeholder="Date of visit 3" />
```

Now, I would like to invoke the datetimepicker something like this:

```
$('.dateclass').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        showClose: true,
        widgetPositioning: {
            horizontal: 'left',
            vertical: 'bottom'
        }
    });
```

But this doesn't work. The input boxes in html are actually populated dynamically through knockout, hence the I am not able to use ids.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: try afterRender to put your datetimepicker initilaizer code

Comment: Use a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)

Answer (score 0):

try [Template Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)

you can put your code in **afterRender** hook of knockout lifecycle.
Not a regular knockoutjs user.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you need to open only one datepicker by class name and not by id. If that is that case you can do this.

```
$('.dateclass').click(function () {
    $(this).datetimepicker({
          //your definations
        }
    });
});
```

What the above code does is that it listens to the click event of the class that was clicked on, then it selects that dom and triggers the datetimepicker on that dom.